# ¿Cómo activar o desactivar select con el click en un checkbox, ambos contenidos en datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables, checkbox

Estoy trabajando con el plugin para jquery de Datatables.net, en el que tengo un checkbox, un campo numero y un select que contiene varias opciones, lo que necesito es que el check que corresponde al row habilite el select cuando este checkeado. Todos los select son creados "disabled".

Este es un trozo de la pagina jsp que crea la tabla:

```
<table id="tabla" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
            <tr>
             <th></th>
         <th>Numero</th>        
           <th>Vendedor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
<c:forEach items="${model.lista}" var="item">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name ="${item}" id="${item}"         value="${item}"></td>
     <td ><c:out value="${item}" /></td> 
 <td>
 <select name="${item}" id="${item}" disabled>
<c:forEach var="item" items="${model.listaVendedor}">  
 <option name="nombre" value="${item.razonSocial}"><c:out value="${item.razonSocial}" /></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>     
 </td>                     
</tr>
  </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

este es el trozo de Js con el que estoy trabajando:

```
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').on( "click", function() {  


         var name = $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("name")

    if (this.checked) {
   alert(name);
        $('select[name='+name+']').removeAttr('disabled')
    } else {
        $('select[name='+name+']').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }




});

$("form").on('submit', function(e){
   var $form = $(this);

   // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
   table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
     // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
     if(!$.contains(document, this)){
        // If checkbox is checked
         if(this.checked){
          // Create a hidden element 
           $form.append(
              $('<input>')
              .attr('type', 'hidden')
              .attr('name', this.name)
              .val(this.value)
          );
       }
    } 
  }); 

 table.$('#select').each(function(){

   if(!$.contains(document, this)){

       if($("#select option").is(':selected')){
           var data=$( "#select option:selected" ).text();
          if (data !=null){ // Create a hidden element 
            $form.append(
               $('<input>')
                  .attr('type', 'hidden')
                  .attr('name', this.name)
                  .val(this.value)
            );
         }
      }
        } 

   })

    });
```

Pero no estaría funcionado,uno de los problemas es que el evento del click se queda con el primer check que se clickea, he intentado de varias maneras pero se pierde al cambiar de pagina en la tabla.Tengo entendido que esto es por que Jquery no carga todos los datos en el dom por cuestiones de rendimiento.

Para luego recorrer todo la tabla y enviar en un form todos los datos. Es decir solo lo q fue checkeado y habilitado.

Alguna idea ?

Comment: Si mostrar un ejemplo reproducciendo el error nos ayudarias mucho a encontrate la respuesta.

Comment: te recomendaría cambiar: `.click(function(){` por `.on( "click", function() {` ya que da el click da problemas en ajax, el On no.  me avisas si te ayuda en algo...

Comment: ¿El checkbox y el select tienen el mismo name? Deberías compartir no sólo el JS que falla sino también el HTML para que podamos ver el error directamente y así poder ayudarte mejor. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y consejos.

Comment: fue agregado el trozo de jsp que crea la tabla

Comment: @Einer no hay ningun error, no funciona directamente.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si, tienen el mismo name , por que al darle click al check uso el nombre para ubicar el select por el name y asi habilitarlo para q pueda ser desplegado, me tengo q asegurar que solo sean despleagados los select que previamente fueron chequeados.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez no entiendo por que me mandas a la api de AWS.